# XAML Binding to Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, xaml, data-binding

I have a SQL Server DB with the following tables and relationships:

Jobs which contains many sessions.
Sessions which contains many breaks.

First of all, dont be frightened by the large amount of code posted here. The relevant parts are the highlighted parts dealing with the list, the rest is just for comparison to see where I am going wrong.

In XAML I am trying and succeeding when binding jobs. I get it to filter out the correct sessions. No problem there.

My problem is that when I try to get it to filter the breaks that belong to each session it wont work but I am using all the same principles.

I am not using (nor interested in using) Linq2Sql as it creates too many additional classes that bloat my code. I am just using direct databinding.

I have asked this question before and posted code, but I never got any reply because the code was simply too long to read in a reasonable timeframe.

My question here is, what am I doing wrong. I was with the impression that since I can successfully bind and filter sessions, then I should be able to do likewise with sessions and filter breaks. But it doesnt work.

I am getting somewhat desparate for help and appreicate any answers.

EDIT: Once again I have included code samples. I am not trying to hide the code for secrecy and copyright. It is just an exercise I am doing to learn so I wouldnt mind posting the full code. But it is very long. So I will just post the parts I think are relevant. If you want more just ask.

For those of you interested in skipping to the good part where the problems are, look under the part of the Breaks list box. The rest is just there for comparison to help you debug. There is also C# code below to help further. Again, look at the list part the rest is just for debugging.

Below is the relevant XAML

```
<!--Jobs List box - Works fine-->
<ListBox Name="lstJobs"  DockPanel.Dock="Top"
        MinWidth="150" MinHeight="200" MaxHeight="250"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        SelectionChanged="lstJobs_SelectionChanged"

        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
        DataContext="{Binding Tables[JobDetails]}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding}"
        >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3,0,3,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text=" "/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ID}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<!--How Jobs listbox is bound to relevant fields in jobs table. This works fine-->
<TextBox    Text="{Binding        ElementName=lstJobs, Path=SelectedItem.ID,            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name="txtJobNo"          Grid.Row="1"                 IsEnabled="False"/>
<TextBox    Text="{Binding        ElementName=lstJobs, Path=SelectedItem.Title,         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name="txtJobTitle"       Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
<TextBox    Text="{Binding        ElementName=lstJobs, Path=SelectedItem.Description,   UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name="txtJobDesc"        Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>


<!--Sessions List box, Automatically filtered based on relationship (see last binding line). This works fine too-->
<ListBox Name="lstSessions" DockPanel.Dock="Top" MinWidth="150"
        MinHeight="200" MaxHeight="220"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        SelectionChanged="lstSessions_SelectionChanged"

        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
        DataContext="{Binding Path=Tables[JobDetails]}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=relJobDetailsSessionDetails}"
        >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3,0,3,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ID}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<!--How Sessions listbox is bound to relevant fields in Sessions table. This works fine-->
<TextBox Name="txtSessionNo"          Text="{Binding ElementName=lstSessions, Path=SelectedItem.ID,            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
<TextBox Name="txtSessionTitle"       Text="{Binding ElementName=lstSessions, Path=SelectedItem.Title,         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
<TextBox Name="txtSessionDesc"        Text="{Binding ElementName=lstSessions, Path=SelectedItem.Description,   UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>


<!--Breaks List box, Should be automatically filtered (it is), but it does not change when a job or session is selected. Why?? -->
<ListBox Name="lstBreaks" MinWidth="150" MinHeight="140" MaxHeight="140"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        SelectionChanged="lstBreaks_SelectionChanged"

        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
        DataContext="{Binding Path=Tables[SessionDetails]}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=relSessionDetailsBreakDetails}"
        >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3,0,3,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ID}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<!--How Breaks listbox is bound to relevant fields in Breaks table. This works fine as before-->
<TextBox Name="txtBreakNo"          Text="{Binding ElementName=lstBreaks, Path=SelectedItem.ID,            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
<TextBox Name="txtBreakTitle"       Text="{Binding ElementName=lstBreaks, Path=SelectedItem.Title,         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
<ComboBox Name="cbxBreakType"       Text="{Binding ElementName=lstBreaks, Path=SelectedItem.Description,     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"/>
```

Following is the C# Code behind (Once again, the highlighted part is the breaks and the rest is just for comparison, so you can skip directly to that if you like):

```
//Connection String
string conString = "XYZ Works ok, no prob here";

//Data Adaptors for various tables
SqlDataAdapter daJobDetails = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlDataAdapter daSessionDetails = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlDataAdapter daBreakDetails = new SqlDataAdapter();

//The dataset to hold all of the data
DataSet dsDataSet = new DataSet();

//Step 1: Create Connection
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString);

//Open Connection
conn.Open();


//Load Job Details Table - works fine.
daJobDetails.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * From JobDetails", conn);
daJobDetails.Fill(dsDataSet, "JobDetails");

//Load Session Details table - works fine.
daSessionDetails.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SessionDetails", conn);
daSessionDetails.Fill(dsDataSet, "SessionDetails");

//Relation: JobDetails.ID = SessionDetails.JobID. - Works fine
dsDataSet.Relations.Add("relJobDetailsSessionDetails",
    dsDataSet.Tables["JobDetails"].Columns["ID"],
    dsDataSet.Tables["SessionDetails"].Columns["JobID"]);


//**** Possible problem code *****
//Load Break Details table - could there be something wrong here.
daBreakDetails.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM BreakDetails", conn);
daBreakDetails.Fill(dsDataSet, "BreakDetails");

//**** Possible problem code *****
//Relation: SessionDetails.ID = BreakDetails.SessionID - Could there be something wrong here
dsDataSet.Relations.Add("relSessionDetailsBreakDetails",
    dsDataSet.Tables["SessionDetails"].Columns["ID"],
    dsDataSet.Tables["BreakDetails"].Columns["SessionID"]);



//Set the DataContext to the DataSet
expJobs.DataContext = dsDataSet;


//Close connection
conn.Close();
```

Comment: I think you're in a catch-22 here, because I can't see how anyone could help you without seeing the code.

Comment: @PhilSandler Code added as requested. Cheers.

Comment: Any binding errors in the output window?  Anything happening in the selectionChanged events?

Comment: @PhilSandler There are no selectionchanged events used. The code doesnt need them. The relationships and binding do all the work. What you are looking at is literally 90% of the code. The other 10% is the usual c# usings, method names, and xaml containers. Dont ask me how it is detecting the selected item and putting the data in the fields. I dont have a clue. I just know it works for jobs/sessions but not for sessions/breaks.

Comment: I asked about the selectionChanged because the handlers are referenced in your listboxes. These methods are empty? If one of them has "e.Handled = true" being set, it *could* explain the problem you are having, I think.

Comment: I am stumped.  I actually curious as to why this wasn't working, so I created some test datatables/relations/data and reproduced the problem exactly as described.  I can post that code if you want so others can have an easier repro, otherwise I would suggest posting this to a more specialized site (like microsoft forums).  Frustrating problem!

Comment: @PhilSandler I did have event handlers for them but they were empty. So removed them from both code and XAML. No change. Can you explain where I need to check for e.Handled = true. Is is the properties, code or XAML, or some other resource file. Failing this, I will go to the ms forums. I would like to see the code you wrote, especially if you were able to come close to solving the problem or even replicating it, as it might give me a clue somewhere. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: The "e.Handled = true" would be in the SelectionChanged event handlers.  You do reference these in your XAML (e.g. SelectionChanged="lstSessions_SelectionChanged"), so I assume they exist, but it sounds like you are not doing anything inside of them.  In any case, I posted my repro as an answer as it is too long to be a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, here is a full repro case.

Update: updated with the working code from your link.  Looks like the answer was binding to SelectedItem => relation.  Very logical, actually.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height=".33*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height=".33*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height=".33*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--Jobs List box - Works fine-->
        <ListBox Name="lstJobs" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" 
             MinWidth="150"  
             MinHeight="200"  
             MaxHeight="250"          
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"          
             SelectionChanged="lstJobs_SelectionChanged"           
             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"          
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=JobDetails}"                      
             >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3,0,3,0">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ID}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <!--How Jobs listbox is bound to relevant fields in jobs table. This works fine-->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=lstJobs, Path=SelectedItem.ID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
             Name="txtJobNo" Grid.Row="1" IsEnabled="False"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=lstJobs, Path=SelectedItem.Title, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
             Name="txtJobTitle" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=lstJobs, Path=SelectedItem.Description, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
             Name="txtJobDesc" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--Sessions List box, Automatically filtered based on relationship (see last binding line). This works fine too -->
        <ListBox Name="lstSessions" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" 
             DockPanel.Dock="Top"  
             MinWidth="150"          
             MinHeight="200"  
             MaxHeight="220"          
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"          
             SelectionChanged="lstSessions_SelectionChanged"           
             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"          
             ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=lstJobs, Path=SelectedItem.relJobDetailsSessionDetails}" 
             >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3,0,3,0">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ID}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>


        <!--How Sessions listbox is bound to relevant fields in Sessions table. This works fine-->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBox Name="txtSessionNo" Text="{Binding ElementName=lstSessions, Path=SelectedItem.ID,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
             Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <TextBox Name="txtSessionTitle" Text="{Binding ElementName=lstSessions, Path=SelectedItem.Title, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
             Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
            <TextBox Name="txtSessionDesc" Text="{Binding ElementName=lstSessions, Path=SelectedItem.Description, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
             Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--Breaks List box, Should be automatically filtered (it is), but it does not change when a job or session is selected. Why?? -->
        <ListBox Name="lstBreaks" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" 
             MinWidth="150"  
             MinHeight="140"  
             MaxHeight="140"          
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"          
             SelectionChanged="lstBreaks_SelectionChanged"           
             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"          
             ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=lstSessions, Path=SelectedItem.relSessionDetailsBreakDetails}"          
             >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3,0,3,0">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ID}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <!--How Breaks listbox is bound to relevant fields in Breaks table. This works fine as before-->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
            <TextBox Name="txtBreakNo" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"  
             Text="{Binding ElementName=lstBreaks, Path=SelectedItem.ID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
             Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <TextBox Name="txtBreakTitle" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" 
             Text="{Binding ElementName=lstBreaks, Path=SelectedItem.Title, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
             Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"/>
            <ComboBox Name="cbxBreakType" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" 
              Text="{Binding ElementName=lstBreaks, Path=SelectedItem.Description, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
              Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3"/>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>


</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CreateData();
            this.DataContext = Data;
        }


    public DataSet Data { get; set; }

    private void CreateData()
    {
        Data = new DataSet();
        Data.Tables.Add(CreateJobTable());
        Data.Tables.Add(CreateSessionsTable());
        Data.Tables.Add(CreateBreaks());

        DataRelation relation = GetJobSessionRelations();
        DataRelation relation2 = GetSessionBreakRelations();

        Data.Relations.AddRange(new[] {relation, relation2});
    }

    private DataTable CreateJobTable()
    {
        var jobs = new DataTable();
        jobs.TableName = "JobDetails";
        var col1 = new DataColumn("ID");
        var col2 = new DataColumn("Title");
        var col3 = new DataColumn("Description");

        col1.DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
        col2.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
        col3.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");

        jobs.Columns.Add(col1);
        jobs.Columns.Add(col2);
        jobs.Columns.Add(col3);

        DataRow row = jobs.NewRow();
        row["ID"] = 1;
        row["Title"] = "Job 1";
        row["Description"] = "Job Desc 1";
        jobs.Rows.Add(row);

        DataRow row2 = jobs.NewRow();
        row2["ID"] = 2;
        row2["Title"] = "Job 2";
        row2["Description"] = "Job Desc 2";
        jobs.Rows.Add(row2);

        return jobs;
    }

    private DataTable CreateSessionsTable()
    {
        var sessions = new DataTable();
        sessions.TableName = "SessionDetails";
        var col1 = new DataColumn("ID");
        var col2 = new DataColumn("Title");
        var col3 = new DataColumn("Description");
        var col4 = new DataColumn("JobID");

        col1.DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
        col2.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
        col3.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
        col4.DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int32");

        sessions.Columns.Add(col1);
        sessions.Columns.Add(col2);
        sessions.Columns.Add(col3);
        sessions.Columns.Add(col4);

        DataRow row = sessions.NewRow();
        row["ID"] = 1;
        row["Title"] = "Session 1";
        row["Description"] = "Session Desc 1";
        row["JobID"] = 1;
        sessions.Rows.Add(row);

        DataRow row2 = sessions.NewRow();
        row2["ID"] = 2;
        row2["Title"] = "Session 2";
        row2["Description"] = "Session Desc 2";
        row2["JobID"] = 1;
        sessions.Rows.Add(row2);

        DataRow row3 = sessions.NewRow();
        row3["ID"] = 3;
        row3["Title"] = "Session 3";
        row3["Description"] = "Session Desc 3";
        row3["JobID"] = 2;
        sessions.Rows.Add(row3);

        DataRow row4 = sessions.NewRow();
        row4["ID"] = 4;
        row4["Title"] = "Session 4";
        row4["Description"] = "Session Desc 4";
        row4["JobID"] = 2;
        sessions.Rows.Add(row4);

        return sessions;
    }

    private DataTable CreateBreaks()
    {
        var breaks = new DataTable();
        breaks.TableName = "BreakDetails";
        var col1 = new DataColumn("ID");
        var col2 = new DataColumn("Title");
        var col3 = new DataColumn("Description");
        var col4 = new DataColumn("SessionID");

        col1.DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
        col2.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
        col3.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
        col4.DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int32");

        breaks.Columns.Add(col1);
        breaks.Columns.Add(col2);
        breaks.Columns.Add(col3);
        breaks.Columns.Add(col4);

        DataRow row = breaks.NewRow();
        row["ID"] = 1;
        row["Title"] = "Break 1";
        row["Description"] = "Break Desc 1";
        row["SessionID"] = 1;
        breaks.Rows.Add(row);

        DataRow row2 = breaks.NewRow();
        row2["ID"] = 2;
        row2["Title"] = "Break 2";
        row2["Description"] = "Break Desc 2";
        row2["SessionID"] = 2;
        breaks.Rows.Add(row2);

        DataRow row3 = breaks.NewRow();
        row3["ID"] = 3;
        row3["Title"] = "Break 3";
        row3["Description"] = "Break Desc 3";
        row3["SessionID"] = 3;
        breaks.Rows.Add(row3);


        DataRow row4 = breaks.NewRow();
        row4["ID"] = 4;
        row4["Title"] = "Break 4";
        row4["Description"] = "Break Desc 4";
        row4["SessionID"] = 4;
        breaks.Rows.Add(row4);

        return breaks;
    }

    private DataRelation GetSessionBreakRelations()
    {
        return new DataRelation("relJobDetailsSessionDetails", Data.Tables["JobDetails"].Columns["ID"],
                                Data.Tables["SessionDetails"].Columns["JobID"]);
    }

    private DataRelation GetJobSessionRelations()
    {
        var dataRelation = new DataRelation("relSessionDetailsBreakDetails", Data.Tables["SessionDetails"].Columns["ID"],
                                            Data.Tables["BreakDetails"].Columns["SessionID"]);
        return dataRelation;
    }

    private void lstJobs_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void lstSessions_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void lstBreaks_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Me too, especially considering nobody else even bothered to answer not to mind taking the time you took to research it. I have upvoted it again. And will do likewise with all your comments as a thanks for your time.

Comment: Also, I am currently doing assignments in college (this is not part of it so dont worry), I just wanted to let you know it will take me a little time to study your code and let you know what I find out. Meanwhile, if you find an answer, please do post, it will be much appreicated.

Comment: I like the way you went about doing this. I did everything in the window loaded event. But yours breaks it down and seems a lot more professional and easier to work on. Even though there is a bizillion more lines of code.

Comment: I had a little bit of time to go over it. Nice work. It reproduces the problem exactly and as your code is neater than mine, I would like to ask for permission to use it on the microsoft forums you recommended. I will of course, give due credit.

Comment: Also I tested all 8 possible combinations of e.handled as you suggested. But no combination makes it work any different, I dont know if that is any help.

Comment: Feel free to post the code on any forum you like.  If you find something out, let me know.

Comment: I just posted your code. Sorry to take so long but I have a lot of stuff on with college and assignments right now. Here is the link if you want to track the progress. But I will post the answer here when it comes, or if you want to I will give you the points for the accepted answer. - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/f0213fc6-7b3e-405c-8459-2803b1bf46a1/#f0213fc6-7b3e-405c-8459-2803b1bf46a1

Comment: Hey my friend. The answer to this was just posted on the link I provided. I tested it and it works. So problem solved. If you want to copy and paste it here I will give you the marks for the selected answer as a thank you for pointing me where to go. Thanks for all your help and for your patience.

Comment: That's kind of you--updated.  Thanks for following up, the answer is satisfying because it actually makes perfect sense.  Once I started tinkering with this, it was driving me crazy trying to work out the answer.